# Catch exception when it doesn't find any member from AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I made this code to check the groups and authorities of every member in a AD Group for that specific drive. It works for every drive I select, but it breaks when it finds both and AD group and user as member.

> Get-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'GF05856_ADM' under: 'DC=gescoeurope,DC=fiatgesco,DC=com'.

It breaks because it tries to search the member inside the group, but it can't find any member inside a user.

```cs
cls
$result = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Select the path of the drive.`n" + "Once the Drive is selected, a excel file will be made with all the informations`n" + "of the selected Harddrive's directory premissions")
if ($result = "OK") {
  Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
  $FolderBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
  [void]$FolderBrowser.ShowDialog()
  $Selection = $FolderBrowser.SelectedPath
}
$result2 = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Pleas select where to save your file")
if ($result2 = "OK") {
  Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
  $FolderBrowser2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
  [void]$FolderBrowser2.ShowDialog()
  $FolderBrowser2.Description = "Select where to save your file"
  $Selection2 = $FolderBrowser2.SelectedPath
}

$ss =$Selection1 -replace '[\W]', ''
$subtitle = "HardDrive" + $ss

$OutFile = ($Selection2 + "\" + $subtitle + $title)
Write-Host = $OutFile

if (Test-Path $OutFile -PathType Leaf) {
  $result3 = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("The file already exists in the selected path`n" + "Do you want to delete it and proceed ?", 'File already exists', 'YesNoCancel', 'Exclamation')
  if ($result3 = "Yes") {
    Remove-Item $OutFile
    $Header = "Folder Path,IdentityReference,names"

    $RootPath = $Selection

    $Folders = dir $RootPath  | where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true}
```

Here is the main code:

```cs
  try {
    foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {
      $ACLs = Get-Acl $Folder.FullName |
              ForEach-Object { $_.Access } |
              where {$_.IdentityReference -notmatch $exclude}
      foreach ($ACL in $ACLs) {
        if ($ACL.IdentityReference -notlike "Administrators" -and $ACL.IdentityReference -notlike "Creator Owner"-and $ACL.IdentityReference -notlike "BUILTIN\Administrators" -and $ACL.IdentityReference -notlike "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -and  $ACL.IdentityReference -notlike "System") {
          $strAcls = $ACL.IdentityReference.ToString()
          $strUsers = @()
          $strNames = $strAcls.Remove(0, 12)
          $user = $(try {Get-ADUser $DN} catch {$null})

          if ($strNames -ne $null) {
            $A = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $strNames -Recursive |
                 Get-ADUser -Property DisplayName |
                 Select Name |
                 Sort-Object Name
          } else {
          }

          foreach ($env:USERNAME in $A) {
            $strUsers += $env:USERNAME
          }
          $OutInfo = $Folder.FullName + "," + $ACL.IdentityReference + $strUsers
        }
      }
    }
  } catch [System.IO.IOException] {
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for this bad explanation, but  I am not so good in English. Hope you can help me

Comment: Since you are already getting if its a user, add a check if it is a user before you do the group member lookup. `if (($strNames -ne $null) -and ($users -eq $null)) {`

Comment: @BenH ITYM `... -and $user -eq $null`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I did mean `$user`

Comment: That's what I thought. ;)